# How to call plugin controller action from base application?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am developing a CakePHP app and I installed Silas Montgomery's Cake FullCalendar Plugin.

I have created a table to log when people attend to events which are managed by the plugin.  So I have this model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Attendance extends AppModel {
public $primaryKey = 'idattendance';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'PeopleAttendance' => array(
        'className' => 'People',
        'foreignKey' => 'idpeople',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'AttendanceEvent' => array(
        'className' => 'FullCalendar.Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'idevent',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
}
```

How can I call a FullCallendar action (say add() to add events) from within an Attendance view?

This works...

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('New Event'),'http://localhost:8888/project/full_calendar/events/add');
```

... but it doesn't seem "Cake-correct" to me...

What should be the best approach when using such type of plugin?  Also, I haven't fully tested, but I would guess my model is not correct either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an option "plugin" to your link array:

```
$this->Html->link(__('New Event'), array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'add', 'plugin' => 'full_calendar'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Out of plain curiosity.  If I BAKE the view, why doesn't Cake figure out the correct link by look at the associations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `plugin` option to link to a plugin action:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    __('New Event'),
    array(
        'plugin' => 'full_calendar', // Define the plugin here as option
        'controller' => 'events',
        'action' => 'add'
    )
);
```